# Edit My Recent Post Widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress theme that I bought, many different widgets come with it.
I have one with the following code and, what it does is that shows the Recent Posts.
I need to make a change in it, actually two, instead of showing me the recent POST I need it to show me the recent portfolio items and only of a certain category.

```
<?php
// =============================== My Recent Posts (News widget) ======================================
class MY_PostWidget extends WP_Widget {
    /** constructor */
    function MY_PostWidget() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'My - Recent Posts');  
    }

  /** @see WP_Widget::widget */
    function widget($args, $instance) {     
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
                $category = apply_filters('widget_category', $instance['category']);
                $linktext = apply_filters('widget_linktext', $instance['linktext']);
                $linkurl = apply_filters('widget_linkurl', $instance['linkurl']);
                $count = apply_filters('widget_count', $instance['count']);
        ?>
              <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
                  <?php if ( $title )
                        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>

                        <?php  $temp = $wp_query;
                                     $wp_query= null;
                                     $wp_query = new WP_Query();  ?>

                                <ul class="latestpost">

                                <?php $querycat = $category; ?>

                                <?php $wp_query->query("showposts=". $count ."&category_name=". $querycat); ?>

                                <?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
                                <li>
                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                            echo '<figure class="featured-thumbnail"><a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '">';
                            echo the_post_thumbnail('small-post-thumbnail');
                            echo '</a></figure>';
                            }
                          ?>
                  <time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i'); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_time('[m-d-Y]'); ?></a></time>
                  <?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo my_string_limit_words($excerpt,13);?>
                                </li>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </ul>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>


                                <!-- Link under post cycle -->
                                <?php if($linkurl !=""){?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $linkurl; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $linktext; ?></a>
                                <?php } ?>


              <?php echo $after_widget; ?>

        <?php
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::update */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {             
        return $new_instance;
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::form */
    function form($instance) {              
      $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
            $category = esc_attr($instance['category']);
            $linktext = esc_attr($instance['linktext']);
            $linkurl = esc_attr($instance['linkurl']);
            $count = esc_attr($instance['count']);
        ?>
      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'theme1472'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></label></p>

      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>"><?php _e('Category Slug:', 'theme1472'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('category'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" /></label></p>

      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>"><?php _e('Posts per page:'); ?><input class="widefat" style="width:30px; display:block; text-align:center" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('count'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $count; ?>" /></label></p>

             <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linktext'); ?>"><?php _e('Link Text:', 'theme1472'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linktext'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('linktext'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $linktext; ?>" /></label></p>

             <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linkurl'); ?>"><?php _e('Link Url:', 'theme1472'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linkurl'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('linkurl'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $linkurl; ?>" /></label></p>
        <?php 
    }

} // class  Widget
?>
```

This is how it looks like now in the widget pane:

[image: Widget]

Answer (score 2):

here in this line

```
<?php $wp_query->query("showposts=". $count ."&category_name=". $querycat); ?>
```

replace with

```
<?php $wp_query->query("showposts=". $count ."&category_name=". $querycat."&post_type=portfolio"); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Bhumi, I tried and for some reason it doesn't work. In the theme there is a section called "Collections" which when clicked it goes in the portfolio section (as it links to /portfolio-view/...). So I guess I have to place that part of the code as you said, but it doesn't work. Do you think is there any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar widget like yours. I was able to get mine to work with help from the answer above. Hopefully this will help you or someone else out.

```
    <?php
// =============================== My Recent Portfolio (News widget) ======================================
class MY_PortfolioWidget extends WP_Widget {
    /** constructor */
    function MY_PortfolioWidget() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'My - Recent Portfolio');  
    }

  /** @see WP_Widget::widget */
    function widget($args, $instance) {     
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
                $category = apply_filters('widget_category', $instance['category']);
                $post_format = apply_filters('widget_post_format', $instance['post_format']);
                $linktext = apply_filters('widget_linktext', $instance['linktext']);
                $linkurl = apply_filters('widget_linkurl', $instance['linkurl']);
                $count = apply_filters('widget_count', $instance['count']);
                $excerpt_count = apply_filters('widget_excerpt_count', $instance['excerpt_count']);

        ?>
              <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
                  <?php if ( $title )
                        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>



                        <?php if($post_format == 'post-format-standard') { 

                            $args = array(
                                        'showposts' => $count,
                                        'portfolio_category' => $category,
                                        'post_type' => portfolio,
                                        'tax_query' => array(
                                         'relation' => 'AND',
                                            array(
                                                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                                                'field' => 'slug',
                                                'terms' => array('post-format-aside', 'post-format-gallery', 'post-format-link', 'post-format-image', 'post-format-quote', 'post-format-audio', 'post-format-video'),
                                                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                                            )
                                        )
                                        );

                        } else { 

                            $args = array(
                                'showposts' => $count,
                                'category_name' => $category,
                                'post_type' => portfolio,
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                 'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => array($post_format)
                                    )
                                )
                                );

                        } ?>




                        <div class="latestpost-container">
                            <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
                                <ul class="latestpost">



                                <?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();?>

                                <li class="clearfix">
                                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                                        <?php
                                        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get img URL
                                        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 200, 146, true); //resize & crop img
                                        ?>
                                        <figure class="featured-thumbnail">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
                                        </figure>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                        <div class="post-meta">
                                            <time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i'); ?>"><?php the_time('l, j F Y'); ?></time>
                                            <?php _e('By', 'theme1796'); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link() ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php _e('Permanent Link to', 'theme1796');?> <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                    <?php if($excerpt_count!="") { ?>
                                        <div class="excerpt">
                                            <?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo my_string_limit_words($excerpt,$excerpt_count);?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="post-footer">
                                            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '<span>1</span> Comment', '<span>%</span> Comments', 'comments-link', 'Comments are closed'); ?>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="link"><?php _e('Read more', 'theme1796'); ?></a>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </li>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </ul>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

                                <!-- Link under post cycle -->
                                <?php if($linkurl !=""){?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $linkurl; ?>" class="link"><?php echo $linktext; ?></a>
                                <?php } ?>

                        </div>                      




              <?php echo $after_widget; ?>

        <?php
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::update */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {             
        return $new_instance;
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::form */
    function form($instance) {              
      $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
            $category = esc_attr($instance['category']);
            $post_format = esc_attr($instance['post_format']);
            $linktext = esc_attr($instance['linktext']);
            $linkurl = esc_attr($instance['linkurl']);
            $count = esc_attr($instance['count']);
            $excerpt_count = esc_attr($instance['excerpt_count']);
        ?>
      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'theme1796'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></label></p>

      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>"><?php _e('Category Slug:', 'theme1796'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('category'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" /></label></p>

            <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_format'); ?>"><?php _e('Post format:', 'theme1796'); ?><br />

      <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_format'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('post_format'); ?>" style="width:150px;" > 
            <option value="post-format-standard" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-standard' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Standard</option>
      <option value="post-format-aside" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-aside' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Aside</option>
            <option value="post-format-quote" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-quote' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Quote</option>
            <option value="post-format-link" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-link' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Link</option>
            <option value="post-format-image" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-image' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Image</option>
      <option value="post-format-gallery" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-gallery' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Gallery</option>
            <option value="post-format-audio" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-audio' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Audio</option>
            <option value="post-format-video" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-video' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Video</option>
      </select>
      </label></p>

      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>"><?php _e('Posts per page:'); ?><input class="widefat" style="width:30px; display:block; text-align:center" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('count'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $count; ?>" /></label></p>

            <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('excerpt_count'); ?>"><?php _e('Excerpt length (words):'); ?><input class="widefat" style="width:30px; display:block; text-align:center" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('excerpt_count'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('excerpt_count'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $excerpt_count; ?>" /></label></p>

             <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linktext'); ?>"><?php _e('Link Text:', 'theme1796'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linktext'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('linktext'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $linktext; ?>" /></label></p>

             <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linkurl'); ?>"><?php _e('Link Url:', 'theme1796'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linkurl'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('linkurl'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $linkurl; ?>" /></label></p>
        <?php 
    }

} // class Widget
?>
```